# Объединение двух сетей через OpenVPN

Tags: сеть, openvpn

Есть необходимость объединить домашнюю и дачную подсети.

Домашняя сеть (192.168.0.0) имеет static ip и на входе стоит роутер Asus ac86u, на котором включен openvpn-сервер c дефолтными настройками.
Дачная сеть (192.168.7.0) работает под tp-link 3020 с установленным OpenWRT и OpenVPN.

VPN-клиент (192.168.7.1) успешно подключается к серверу (192.168.0.1) и получает ip-адрес 10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.5 айпи другого конца тоннеля). VPN-клиент видит сервер по его локальному адресу (192.168.0.1), а также другие компьютеры которые находятся за VPN-сервером - это отлично.

Проблема в том, что VPN-сервер не видит VPN-клиента по его локальному адресу (192.168.7.1), а также другие компьютеры в подсети клиента.

Список роутов на роутере с VPN-сервером с виду правильный:

```
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun21
95.105.128.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.7.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun21
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun21
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
95.105.128.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
0.0.0.0         95.105.128.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

вот кусок из ifconfig:

```
tun21      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:318 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
RX bytes:26172 (25.5 KiB)  TX bytes:36037 (35.1 KiB)
```

это список роутов на роутере с VPN-клиентом:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
```

и кусок из ifconfig:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

В чем может быть проблема? Что нужно сделать, чтобы роутер с VPN-сервером мог видеть подсеть на стороне VPN-клиента?

Comment: что за адреса `10.8.0.9` и `10.8.0.2`?
IP форвардинг на клиенте включен?

Comment: Не будем обращать внимания, что в таблицах маршрутизации совсем другие адреса. Не 10.8.0.6 или 10.8.0.5, а 10.8.0.2 и 10.8.0.9. Может для point-to-point это простая формальность, чтобы всё совпадало, а может и нет. А ещё не помешало бы проверить настройки фаервалла. https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage#lbBG

Comment: Прошу прощения за неточность. Клиент получает динамический ip, и данные которые я привел в таблицах роутинга - из другой сессии.

В клиентском роутинге строчки 2-4 должны быть
`10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0`
`10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0`
`192.168.0.0     10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0`

Т.е. клиент получает ip 10.8.0.6 и 10.8.0.5(другой конец туннеля)
А на сервере 10.8.0.1 и 10.8.0.2 (вход и выход из туннеля)

Comment: И еще небольшое уточнение - эти роутинги, как на сервере, так и на клиенте, добавляются автоматом VPN. Руками сам ничего не прописывал.